# How to pass a void function to another void function?

Tags: c++, windows

I have a text adventure game and when you enter a room it will display some text and then go to the next room. Each room is a function. I would like to make a function that allows me to set the next room (or function) that the original room goes to as this will save me a lot of time. I know the code below doesn't work but is there a way to pass a `void` type function as a parameter of another `void` type function? (shown below)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void room2();
void room1();
void room(void a);

void room1()
{
    cout << "next room" << endl;
}

void room2()
{
    cout << "other rooom" << endl;
}

void room(void a)
{
    cout << "Things happen here now you go to the next room" << endl;
    a();
}

int main()
{
    room(nextRoom());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cpp
// declare a type of function pointer
typedef void (*room_ptr)();

// declare a method that takes a function pointer as arg
void room(room_ptr a)
{
    // call the function passed in... 
    a();
}

// store the current room 
room_ptr current_room = room1;

// easy to modify later
current_room = room2;

// and just call... 
room(current_room);
```

Comment: What does the `typedef` statement do? I've never worked with or seen it before.

Comment: It makes an alias for a type, for shorthand. Whenever you refer to `room_ptr`, the compiler substitutes that with `void (*)()`

Comment: ahh ok, so it is sort of like an object for a class? like `test t;`

Comment: A more readable alternative is `using room_ptr = void (*)();`.

Comment: You actually don't even need to store the room you want to pass as a parameter in `current_room` you can just call the function itself

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manually specifying a function pointer type, you can ask a compiler to deduce it:

```
template<class Fn>
void room(Fn fn) {
    // ...
    fn();
}

room(room1);
```

You can now call `room` with a capturing [lambda](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), too:

```
int some_var;
room([some_var]() { ... });
```

(Capturing lambdas cannot be converted into function pointers in contrast to capture-less lambdas.)

Comment: Templates are a compile time construct, which makes them somewhat unsuitable for the OP's question. Storing the state as to which room you are in (either via a func pointer, or a pointer to a virtual base class) is the way to go here.

Comment: @robthebloke, you can write `auto current_room = room1; room(current_room);` without need to introduce a function pointer type.